# C# - Draw one or more HBitmaps on a Bitmap without using Image.FromHBitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing

I receive multiple (small) images stored in HBitmaps (handles to GDI bitmaps) and I want to draw them together in a large C# System.Drawing.Bitmap object. For performance reasons, I don't want to use Image.FromHBitmap to first convert the HBitmaps, as the method makes a copy of the GDI bitmap.

Is there a way to do this? Graphics.DrawImage seems to require System.Drawing Image/Bitmap objects.

I'm using C#/Windows Forms/System.Drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way I can think of is to use the old GDI APIs. In other words, create two device contexts, SelectObject the bitmaps into them and BitBlt on to the other.